# If I was to drop an object on a frictionless surface while traveling at some speed v, would my velocity increase?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

I'm imagining I'm on a frictionless surface and I am holding an object with some mass m while traveling at some velocity v. If I drop the object, will my velocity increase, decrease, or stay the same? As of now, I am under the assumption that the velocity would increase after dropping the object.

Comment: What do you think? What force is exerted on you or your vehicle when you drop the object? Remember that acceleration only happens if a force is applied.

Comment: No force would be exerted on me. If I simply drop the object and don't impart a force on the object then the only force acting on it would be gravity. I guess in that case my velocity would remain the same. is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You, and the object you drop, would continue to have the same horizontal velocity.

Comment: I have an additional question. If I was gliding through the air in some aircraft of mass m at some constant velocity and suddenly released some cargo, would my velocity remain the same? I ask because I did a similar problem the other day wherein the velocity increased upon dropping the cargo. ignoring air resistance of course.

Comment: This is exactly the same: no force is exerted on you, so your velocity stays the same. Of course, that's only if you simply drop it. If you were to eject it forcefully, that assumption no longer holds, and it then depends on the direction in which you eject it.

Comment: If flying, your vertical velocity will increase because you are lighter.